# How do I unlock level 25 of Far Future?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I've been playing Plants vs. Zombies 2, and have made it to the end of Far Future. I've beaten all 75 prior levels of Ancient Egypt, Pirate Seas, and Wild West, and the 24 levels leading up to the turnip of Far Future. The path from the turnip to the 25th level is missing. Is something wrong?

I thought completing it might unlock the blacked-out medieval-looking castle world.

For your information, here is how I went about my gameplay:

1. Downloaded Plants vs. Zombies 5 days ago (April 6th, 2014) - I say this because research shows the Far Future update hit in March 2014.
2. Defeated all of Ancient Egypt (level 25).
3. Unlocked Far Future with Key from Ancient Egypt.
4. Got Key from Far Future and unlocked Wild West.
5. Got Key from Wild West and unlocked Pirate Seas.
6. Defeated Pirate Seas (level 25).
7. Beat to level 20-or-something of Far Future.
8. Defeated Wild West (level 25).
9. Played Far Future to level 24.

Android O/S.

Comment: @StrixVaria - I only gave EA duplicate personal information that they already have from other games.  There is nothing to indicate this level unlocks with a cash sacrifice.

Comment: Platform tags are only necessary if the game works differently on the specific platform you're using.

Comment: the last level is the boss isn't it?  pretty sure its not available yet.

Comment: I have the same problem, I completed level 24 (twice, just to make sure), got the Tile Turnip, but I cannot get to level 25, no path, nothing. So I tried going in another world, then back to Far Future and now there is still no path, but the boss's head is now there, glowing red - still cannot get in the level though. ![screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Snm.jpg)

Comment: that means the level isn't available yet.  Previously level bosses weren't available for some time until they were unlocked via updates.

Comment: @z- Thanks, I only downloaded this for the first time recently; this is quite confusing to new players and could have been easily resolved with a simple dialog box with a message to the user.

Comment: FYI the level is available now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In previous versions, the final level was available for each world as soon as you unlocked it.  [Then they made some big changes to the game](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Plants_vs._Zombies_2:_It%27s_About_Time#Update_History) including keeping level 25 (the boss fight) locked for each world.  Each world's level 25 is unlocked as part of an update.

IMO this mechanic is an attempt to prolong interest in the game without adding more content.  This mechanic was not conveyed well, especially for people who'd already completed a world only to find it now saying 24/25 complete with level 25 mysteriously unavailable.

I assume [Far Future](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Far_Future) will work the same way.  Its level 25 will be unlocked for everyone in some future update.

Comment: Totally not apparent; they should display a message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

it's a Bug!
if you go to other world then see the boss at the end, and then back to level 25 in Far Future you see level 25 is defeated!

Comment: What?  Can you expand on this?  Perhaps provide an example or elaborate the steps to repeat?